# What's the best way to deactive my adblocker for Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, advertising

Ironically, [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/) convinced me to make the Stack Exchange network the only place where my adblocker is deactivated. However, that's easier said than done. I can whitelist `*.stackexchange.com`, but that misses quite a number of sites:

- [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com)
- [superuser.com](https://superuser.com)
- [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com)
- [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com)
- [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net)
- [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com)
- [stackoverflow.blog](https://stackoverflow.blog)
- [stackmod.blog](https://stackmod.blog/)
- [security.blogoverflow.com](https://security.blogoverflow.com)
- [thesffblog.com](https://thesffblog.com)
- [tex-talk.net](http://tex-talk.net)
- [stackoverflowbusiness.com](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com)
- Maybe more? Also, even if I added a rule for all, there could still be more in the future.

So how can I whitelist all Stack Exchange sites in a future-proof and complete way? Is there some common property of all these sites that I can use, maybe the host?

I'm using the Chrome extension [AdGuard](https://adguard.com), but a general solution that works for many different adblockers would of course be very welcome.

<sub>Apart from that, I also have an issue with wildcards in general, but that's something to ask in the AdGuard forum.</sub>

Comment: @Close voter: Why is this considered off-topic? I'm asking if there is a common property to SE sites that I could use.

Comment: The question essentially asks if there's a full list of Stack Exchange domains. It's perfectly on topic.

Comment: @yannis In a way yes. If there's such a list that's guarantueed to stay the same forever. Or, if not, if there's something else I could put into the filter that catches them all.

Comment: @yannis It’s on topic, but a dupe.

Comment: @DanBron The answers there don't mention the blogs and stackoverflowbusiness.com. Should it be updated or this one not be marked as duplicate?

Comment: @Fabian I’d suggest updating that one, as it’s the canonical Q for this topic (which means it’s also easiest to tind and the dupe target for a series of similar questions).

Comment: So, should I just put a bounty on it saying that blogs and stuff should also be included? If yes, how would I award that bounty? The existing community wiki answer should be updated, it doesn't need a new one.

Comment: @Fabian It’s community wiki. Just edit it.

Comment: But I do not know the answer, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Fabian Add the sites you know are missing from the answer. If other people come across others, they can add hem too. That is the point of a CW answer: incremental improvement over time.

Answer (score -1):

A full list of sites would be a bit hard to give, unless it's an official who is going to list them.

You probably don't need that list, practically. You only need to disable AdBlocker on the sites you visit (frequently). A site that you're never going to visit, if added to the whitelist, won't do anything meaningful.

If I were to use AdBlocker, I would only whitelist SO, *.SE, SU, SF, AU and Stack Apps, as well as SO.blog, which are the sites I regularly visit. I rarely visit SO Business or TeX blog , so adding them to the whitelist wouldn't do much useful things. (Note the subjunctive mood in this paragraph - I don't use AB actually. The "reduced ads" on sites that I have 200 rep on is satisfactory already.)

Do practical jobs. No need to do hypothetical jobs.